# Total Gaussian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature, compact-manifolds

For a compact surface, $S$, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, how would I go about showing that the total Gaussian curvature $\int_S K da \leq 4 \pi$? I feel like Hopf's Umlaufsatz and the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem are helpful.

Comment: For closed surfaces it's immediate from the classification of surfaces and the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface

Comment: I think you need to at least assume that the surface is connected. Otherwise you could produce a counterexample by taking two disjoint spheres.

Comment: So it is equivalent to showing that the Euler characteristic on a connected, compact surface cannot exceed 2?

Comment: If you want to deal with surfaces with boundaries it gets more complicated, since then you have an extra term in the Gauss Bonnet formula. But for the closed case it's true. And it's known that the Euler-characteristic for closed, connected, (orientable) surfaces does not exceed 2.